# _e printed before layout WPML/Wordpress/PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, concatenation, wpml

I am using WPML to translate English to a different language.
Everything works fine except the mail form.
For some reason when is use the _e() function the string gets printed before the layout.
But still inside the body element. Please help here is the code:

```
if(trim($_POST['contactSubject']) === '') {
       $subjectError = _e('Please enter a subject.', 'wpml_contact');
       $hasError = true;
} else {
       $subject = trim($_POST['contactSubject']);
}
```

Comment: We would need to see what the `_e` function does.

Comment: The [_e()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e) function displays output, it does not return a value

Comment: It's used to pass the error message into a span.
<?php if($subjectError != '') { ?>
        <span><?=$subjectError;?></span>
      <?php } ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `__()` function ([codex link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2)). This function returns the translated string:

```
if(trim($_POST['contactSubject']) === '') {
   $subjectError = __('Please enter a subject.', 'wpml_contact');
   $hasError = true;
} else {
   $subject = trim($_POST['contactSubject']);
}
```

The `_e()` function returns and displays the translated string.